# Switching university for PhD but staying in the same city

Tags: phd, graduate-admissions

I am currently a graduate student in mathematics at the University of Montreal. I also did my undergraduate studies there.

I know it is often frowned upon to do all your graduate studies at the same university. I have read online it is often better to go somewhere else for your PhD.

How far does one have to go for the PhD studies? 
In Montreal, there are three other universities (McGill, Concordia, UQAM) and I was wondering if just switching university (while staying in the same city) is sufficient in academia. Will it be frowned upon?

Comment: I don't know where it's "frowned upon" to do all your graduate studies at the same universities, but I know of people that stay with the same institution from their first day in undergrad to their PhD. If you feel the need to move, then that's fine. But if you already like your current university climate, I would stay.

Comment: @SeanRoberson See [this answer](https://academia.stackexchange.com/a/51175) and [this one](https://academia.stackexchange.com/a/82808/11192) for some insight into the "frowned upon" aspect of getting multiple degrees from the same institution.

Comment: It's worthwhile to consider the reasons for going to a different university.  Different scholars have different opinions about their subject.  Even in a subject that is 'objective', different scholars have different opinions about which parts of the subject are 'important' or which types of methods are more 'elegant' than others.  Scholars in the same department tend to have similar opinions because, even if they start out with different opinions, over time they adjust their opinions through discussion and their opinions converge.  (continued)

Comment: Hence someone who has all their education at the same university is at serious risk of getting a one-sided view of their subject, with the opinions held by their professors implicitly assumed to be true without even the idea that different opinions on these matters are even possible.  What's important is that one goes some place where prevailing opinions are different.  Other universities in the same city are probably okay, but not if the departments collaborate a lot or if one department dominates all the others.  (continued)

Comment: A university far away might be problematic if most of its professors are graduates of your current university or vice versa (or both are dominated by graduates of the same third university).

Comment: I stayed at the same university for Bachelors, Masters and PhD. Even in the same group where I did my masters. So far, it does not hurt at all. If I would not want to move for personal reasons, I would be definitely thinking about staying here. Here I have an academic network (that I will try to not lose contact with when moving) and collaborators. At the place I plan to move to unfortunately, I will have nothing at the start.

Comment: @skymningen From what I have heard it is difficult.to find a good post doc if you have stayed in the same university for all your studies.

Comment: @skymningen - It is often a good idea to diversify.  It is not always necessary.  But to answer your question, if you're going into a good program in the same city, it seems to me that you would probably still reap the benefits of the diversification factor.